# TypeScript + Redux-Saga: a generator function inside an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a file named static.js where I declare all generator functions:

for example:

```
export function* getSettings() {
    try {
        const settings: Array<SettingElement> = yield callHttp(get, GET_SETTINGS);
        yield put(setSettings(settings));
        }
} catch (err: any) {
        yield put(openErrorSnack(err.message));
    }
}

export function* getSocialLinks() {
    try {
        const social: Array<SocialElement> = yield callHttp(get, GET_SOCIAL);
        yield put(setSocialLinks(social));
    } catch (err: any) {

        yield put(openErrorSnack(err.message));
    }
}
```

In another file named index.ts I want to import all above sagas

```
import * as staticSagas from './static';
```

How should I create a type or interface for these imported sagas?

Thank you for your help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go over the official documentation once.
LINK: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/GettingStarted

According to official documentation we for all the sagas and export the default saga.

```
  yield all([
    fork(getSettings),
    fork(getSocialLinks),
  ]);
}
```

If this is not in the root saga then you need to import it there. If this is your root saga then just link to the sagaMiddleware